# Why am I not seeing the version of ImageMagick that I just installed though the terminal?

Tags: python, macos, imagemagick

I am trying to install ImageMagick on my Mac running Sierra. I installed it using the command: `sudo port install ImageMagick`. This is what I get when I run this command:

```
imagemagick 7.0.6-10 is already installed
```

When I type `identify -version` it states that I have version 6.9.9-5.

Here it is verbatim:

```
    Version: ImageMagick 6.9.9-5 Q16 x86_64 2017-08-29 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png ps tiff webp x xml zlib
```

Is it possible for me to run version 7.0.6? I want to use this library to read PDF's in Python and this seems to be what is keeping me from using it.

Comment: Run `which convert` and `which identify`. See if they've have the same path or not.

Comment: @Zindarod which convert tells me /opt/local/bin/convert and  which identify tells me /opt/local/bin/identify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try typing "magick identify -version" (ImageMagick 7 uses the "magick" prefix for all of its commands)